# Is there a similar library to PixTools for MAC?

Tags: macos, swift

Is there a similar library to PixTools for capturing images, images from a scanner and then treat them with image recognition for OSX operating systems?

PixTools / Scan developers programmatic Gives Control of the Entire scanning process and every scanner feature

I am programming a system in MAC that use a scanner,i am programming in swift.

I require is a library that allows me to manipulate the images and perform OCR as pixtools for .Net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes; what you're looking for are [the ImageKit and ImageCaptureCore frameworks](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/ImageCaptureServicesProgrammingGuide/02Overview/02Overview.html).

Note that ImageKit is a bit more general than PixTools; it handles transferring images from cameras as well as running scanners. However, it does not support some of the more complex image enhancement and recognition features supported by PixTools.

Comment: but i need a library to OCR